# Reusing controller function + extending it

Tags: angularjs

I have a page that consists of several panels that are very similar in their structure. They use one controller each. But due to their similarity i reuse the controller function like so:

```
function panelController($scope) {
 ...
}
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('panel1Controller', panelController);
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('panel2Controller', panelController);
```

The result is that panel1 and panel2 have their own distinct scopes but will look the same in terms of what the view can bind to.

Now however I am at a point where I want to use the same pattern for panel3 but with a slight extension. That is, I have something I want to include only in the $scope for panel3 only. So ideally I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
function panel3ControllerExtension($scope) {
   $scope.panel3Field = "I must only live in panel3";
}
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('panel3Controller', panelController, panel3ControllerExtension);
```

But that's not possible. Are there any good patterns for this out there?

---

Edit:
The similar panels are similar only in what they expect the $scope to contain. Specifically the expect the scope to contain a customer object. So e.g. panel1 binds to $scope.customer.name and panel2 to $scope.customer.phone.  ...So since they look different and behave different I don't think making a directive of them are the way to go. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You should try using a service for reusable parts of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Controllers in Angular are used effectively as constructors. So the rules for "inheritance" in Javascript apply to them. Some methods for extension:

1. `apply`/`call` the "base" function:

   ```
   function panel3Controller($scope) {
       // add the functionality of `panelController` to this scope
       // in OO terms this can be thought of as calling the `super` constructor
       panelController.call(this, $scope);
       // add panel3 specific functionality
       $scope.panel3SpecificThing = "...";
   }
   // just register the new controller
   angular.module('myApp.controllers')
       .controller('panel3Controller', panel3Controller);
   ```

   This method will probably get you what you want with the minimum modifications to your code.
2. Use JS inheritance: Make the controller a JS "class" and let the child controller prototypically inherit from it. You may also want to use this in conjuction with the `controller as` syntax:

   ```
   function PanelController($scope) {
       this.$scope = $scope;
       this.something = '...';
   }

   PanelController.prototype.someMethod = function() {
       ...
   }

   function Panel3Controller($scope) {
       PanelController.call(this, $scope);
       this.somethingElse = '...';
   }
   Panel3Controller.prototype = new PanelController();
   Panel3Controller.prototype.constructor = Panel3Controller;

   Panel3Controller.prototype.panel3SpecificMehod = function() {
       ...
   };
   ```

   If you are using ES2015, the above can be simplified:

   ```
   class PanelController {
       constructor($scope) {
           ...
       }
       ...
   }

   class Panel3Controller extends PanelController {
       constructor($scope) {
           super($scope);
           ...
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

   Again, you just register the new controller alone:

   ```
   angular.module('myApp.controllers')
       .controller('panel3Controller', Panel3Controller);
   ```

   If the properties and methods are placed in the controller, as shown here, use the `controller as` syntax, i.e. in the HTML:

   ```
   <div ng-controller="panel3Controller as p3ctrl">
       <span>{{ p3ctrl.somethingElse }}</span>
   ```

   Having a module system in place makes this pattern really useful.
3. Depending on the exact functionality of the controllers and, as pointed out in a comment, you may be able to extract the functionality of the controller(s) in one or more services. Then the controllers will be thin wrappers for these services. Again whether this is a good idea or not depends on the exact functionality of the controller(s).

As for directives: they are always the way to go :) And you can reuse your code as the controller of the *directive* instead of using it with `ng-controller`. You can even use two directives with different templates (the `customer.name` and `customer.phone` binding for example) and the same controller.